# Allow user to fill out node form, then force registration

Tags: forms, nodes, users

I'm making a classified website.

Have a button that say "Make a ad"
I would like the Anonymous  user to be able to
fill in the text for the ad.

But the  Anonymous users after filling in advert.
has to sign up for the ad to be posted

How can  do this with drupal please?

many thanks for your help

Best Regards
Charles

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Two suggestions:

- Check out the [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules). There's [a tutorial for your use case described here](https://drupal.org/node/1281466).
- Or use one of the modules already available, e.g. [Inline Registration](https://drupal.org/project/inline_registration).

Answer (score 0):

As a custom solution, you can do something like this.

1. Create your content (or entity) type. Let's assume two fields: title and body
2. Create a custom form, with fields for title and body.
3. In the form submission, programmatically create a node, and add the submitted title and body to the node. Don't save the node. Instead, store it in the session:

   ```
   $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
   $session->set('my_module_registration_node', $node);
   $value = $session->get('my_module_registration_node);
   ```
4. Also in the form submission, redirect the user to the registration form
5. On registration, check for the existence of the node in the session. If it's there, retrieve it, add the new user as the owner, save it, and clear the session.

Alter as necessary. The `tempstore.private` service is an alternative to using the session. It is more powerful, so if you run into problems storing your node in the session, the private tempstore may serve you better.

You can also create a multistep form with two (or more) steps, collecting both the node data and the user data, and in the final submission, programmatically create the user and node at the same time. This way you can have an ajax form that is customized exactly to your system needs.